# OracleSQL how do I search for entries in a big database containing keywords from a keywordlist

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have this big leaked database of AOL search queries (2006) - lets call it QD - and a table with one column, containing all of the keywords I am looking for in each of those queries.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT 
    keywords.keywords AS Keyword,
    COUNT(QD.query) AS Amount
FROM QD, keywords
WHERE QD.query LIKE ('%' keywords.keywords '%' )
GROUP BY keywords.keywords
ORDER BY COUNT(QD.query) DESC;
```

But that somehow doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What does this mean "doesn't work"? Does it return wrong results, no results, or an error message (which)?

Comment: 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Line 4, Row 41

Comment: Try concatenating the arguments of like - `LIKE('%' || keywords.keywords || '%')`.

Comment: Thanks, the Syntax seems to be correct, however SQLDeveloper just doesn't seem to find an end as it keeps on searching. I'll try to give it some time.

Comment: If the database is big, this may well take a long time. You may want to consider creating a [full text index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx).

Comment: @Habubuga update of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Oracle version :

```
SELECT 
    k.keywords AS Keyword,
    count(k.keywords) AS Amount
FROM keywords AS k
JOIN QD AS q 
    ON q.query LIKE ('%' || t2.kwords || '%')
GROUP BY k.keywords
ORDER BY count(k.keywords) DESC;
```

**Be really careful with the case, `Table` is not `table`, and if you used `"table"` then you can't use it without `"` around.** (Or at least it seem to act like that)

---

MySQL one,:

Ok, I think I got it, with the use of JOIN :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f394/2)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    k.keywords AS Keyword,
    count(*) AS Amount
FROM keywords k
INNER JOIN QD q 
    ON q.query LIKE CONCAT('%', k.keywords, '%')
GROUP BY k.keywords
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f394/2/0)**:

```
|  keywords | Amount |
|-----------|--------|
|        at |     34 |
|     Donec |     11 |
|      quis |     10 |
|      amet |      9 |
| vulputate |      5 |
|    ornare |      4 |
|      eros |      2 |
```